# CSS: Keep paragraphs together while wrapping (floating)

Tags: css, css-float

- I have a `float`ing image on the left side.
- Elements  on the right side (text, images ...) should wrap around it.
- The title of an image should not be wrapped separately from the image, when the screen becomes too small).

#### Image: Window is big enough

(grey background added for clear distinction of the element)
[image]

#### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>

<div style="float:left"> 
  <img style="width:150px; height: auto" src="chrome://branding/content/about-logo@2x.png" /> 
</div>
<p>
  foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 

  <div style="background-color: lightgrey;">
  Image title<br>
  <img style="width:120px; height: 40px" src="chrome://branding/content/about-logo@2x.png" />
  </div>
</p>

</body></html>
```

#### Image: Window is too small (**actual**)

[image]

#### Image: Window is too small (**expected**)

[image]

Comment: You might like to put your code through a validator. The div in the p element is closing the p element see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Answer (score 0):

To *keep your paragraphs together* in this situation, you need `display: inline-block` on the parent element.

##### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div style="float:left"> 
  <img style="width:150px; height: auto" src="chrome://branding/content/about-logo@2x.png" /> 
</div>
<p>
  foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 

  <div style="background-color: lightgrey;display: inline-block;">
    Image title<br> 
    <img style="width:120px; height: 40px" src="chrome://branding/content/about-logo@2x.png" />
  </div>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

#### Generalization

(without furhter research I think) you could maybe generalize to *`display: inline-block` on a div will make it keep the paragraphs together*

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
  Image title<br> 
  <img src="" />
</div>
```